# How to get labels with NA value which have no values present in column using cut function?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have default groups to count frequency for. For this I am using cut and table function. I am using include.lowest= TRUE in cut but no luck to get labels which have no values preset while creating breaks. What I want is even if values are not present for a group then there should come NA for that group is it possible?
 below is my code.

```
bins = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,10,20,50,100,200,"max")
bins[length(bins)] <- max(data$wordCount)
ApplyBreaks <- function(x) {
   cut(data$wordCount,breaks = bins, dig.lab=5, include.lowest = TRUE,
  ordered_result = TRUE, labels = c("0-1","1-2","2-3","3-4","4-5","5-10",
  "10-20","20-50","50-100","100-200",paste0("200-,max(data$wordCount))))
}

data$breaks <- sapply(data$wordCount,ApplyBreaks)`
dataTable <- table(data$breaks,useNA = "always")`
```

It outputs as this

[image]

Comment: structure(list(`data$wordCount` = c(16L, 96L, 88L, 590L, 112L, 
3L), breaks = structure(c("10-20", "50-100", "50-100", "200-1004", 
"100-200", "2-3"), .Dim = c(6L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "data$wordCount"))), .Names = c("data$wordCount", 
"breaks"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `cut` like

```
temp <- table(cut(df$wordCount, 
                 breaks = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,10,20,50,100,200, Inf), 
           labels = c("0-1","1-2","2-3","3-4","4-5","5-10","10-20",
                      "20- 50","50-100","100-200","200+")))
temp

#    0-1  1-2  2-3  3-4   4-5    5-10   10-20  20- 50  50-100 100-200    200+ 
#      0    0    1    0     0       0       1       0       2       1       1
```

This will return 0 values for levels which is not present in the data.